# Picasa Web Albums permissions

Tags: permissions, picasa-web-albums

I have a Picasa Web Albums account where I keep company pictures. Oldies, fun stuff, nothing "professional", just "personal" pictures in a professional environment, that cannot be public. I have tried to set them "private", and created a Contact Group - "Coworkers".

On every new album added, I invited the "coworkers" so they had access to the pictures. (it actually sends mass email invitations too)

BUT

we got new coworkers. It seems like I cannot do anything about adding them to the old albums. Only if I go back to the albums and invite the new guys to them, every time we hire. The same issue, if I didn't have the email of a coworker to add him to the Contact Group, only after some time...

I like the Picasa Web Albums, but this seems not doable at this point. Maybe the only way would be if I would move all the pictures to one album (folder) but there are like 11,000 pictures in a few hundred albums.

What I would like to have, is something I find pretty simple:

To have the possibility to add access to ALL the albums for my Contact Group called "coworkers", even if in time I would add one or more users to this group (or maybe remove a user).

Any suggestions[?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/picasa/d2_oi7BqVj4;context-place=topicsearchin/picasa/category$3A(picasa-web-albums)$20is$3Afirstpost%7Csort:relevance) Workarounds? Ideas?

Comment: Picasa Web Albums is mostly deprecated in favor of Google Photos. Is there a reason you haven't made the switch? From what I recall you can share a link to a Google Photo album that all anyone needs is the link. I seem to remember that Picasa Web Albums also offered "unlisted" albums. The downside to that is it is a pain to have to change the URL when you want to remove access from someone.

Comment: @AlE. i know the photos app, but I would still have the same permission issues there as well. Unlisted? Can't do that. that is still too public for us